# Why can sums of powers be expressed as polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, polynomials, summation

The closed form formula for $\sum_{r=1}^n(r^k)$ can be expressed as a polynomial of degree $k+1$, for example $\sum_{r=1}^n(r^2) = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$.

This seems to hold true for all values of $k$. But why can this sum be expressed as a polynomial? Is there a proof (which doesn't rely on Faulhaber's formula) that this sum can always be expressed as a degree $k+1$ polynomial?

Comment: Why would you exclude Faulhaber?  Anyway, it's easy to argue that the finite difference map takes polynomials of degree $≤d$ to those of degree $≤d-1$ and that the kernel is precisely the constants.  Hence it must be surjective.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2697950/general-form-for-sum-of-powers/2698204?r=SearchResults&s=1|52.9635#2698204) for an elementary demonstration that uses only Algebra and induction.  It avoids Calculus, Bernoulli Numbers and Faulhaber.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893693/elementary-proof-of-polynomial-degree-of-sum-of-pth-powers?rq=1 I just found this post which answers the same question.